# ANTLR 4.2.2: mismatched input

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to wtire sort of CSharp grammar in ANTLR4.
Here is the grammar:
http://pastie.org/9197255

Here is the test class:

```
public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
   }
}
```

And here is the error:
line 1:0 mismatched input 'public' expecting ACCESS_MODIFIER

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `public` is matched by both the lexer rules `IDENTIFIER` and `ACCESS_MODIFIER`. ANTLR resolves such an ambiguity by choosing the first one declared in the grammar. In other words, for your grammar, the input `public` will always be an `IDENTIFIER` and never be an `ACCESS_MODIFIER`.

You can resolve this by moving the `IDENTIFIER` rule after the rules for other keywords.